# Polymer, how to adjust padding to internal div on paper-dialog-scrollable

Tags: polymer

The content area of `paper-dialog-scrollable` has a 24px padding on the left and right. I'd like to change that. When the HTML is rendered, it's an in-line style sheet and an in-line div that has the padding. I've tried using the following to no avail. The polymer inline styles come in after my inline style.

DOES NOT WORK:

```
<style>
  .scrollable {
    --paper-dialog-scrollable: {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    };
  }
</style>
```

**In the following image**  it is the div with id="scrollable" that I need to change. I think it is scope=paper-dialog-scrollable-0 that actually sets the padding.

[image]

So how do I adjust padding to internal div on paper-dialog-scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use selectors like `::shadow` and `/deep/` but they are deprecated. If an element doesn't provide the hooks (CSS variables and mixins) then you're basically out of luck and there is non such hook for `.scrollable`.

What you can do, is to create a feature request in the [elements GitHub](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-slider/issues) repo to support additional selectors by mixins.

Another workaround I already used successfully is to add a [style module](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules).

Create a style module like

```
<dom-module id="scrollable-customization">
 <style>
  .scrollable {
    --paper-dialog-scrollable: {
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
    };
  </style>
</dom-module>
```

import it and then "inject" it to the scrollable element

```
var myDomModule = document.createElement('style', 'custom-style');
myDomModule.setAttribute('include', 'scrollable-customization');
Polymer.dom(this.$pdscroll.root).appendChild(myDomModule);
```

I hope the syntax is correct. I use Polymer only with Dart.
The dom-module needs to be a `custom-style` even though this is normally only necessary when used outside a Polymer element.

See also [Styling Polymer paper-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650000/styling-polymer-paper-slider/34650194#34650194)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without injecting that style, I mean by just using the mixin --paper-dialog-scrollable  ?

Comment: I guess not, but not sure. I haven't worked with Polymer for more than a year.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way, just by using the element style, as follow

```
paper-dialog-scrollable { --paper-dialog-scrollable:  { padding: 0 10px; }; }
```