# Apply border radius to paper-checkbox? No mixin available

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Polymer 1.*

Is there a way to apply `border-radius: 50%` to `paper-checkbox` since it does not have a mixin available? and `/deep/` has long been deprecated.

```
      <paper-checkbox
        name="apples"
        class="checkbox"
        value="1">1</paper-checkbox>
```

Comment: You can apply the border radius https://jsfiddle.net/7vmexhtd/, what will be the use-case ?

Comment: @bhansa He probably means to apply the border radius to the checkbox itself (not the container).

Comment: @tony19 so that the checkbox looks like a radio...

Comment: @bhansa Yes, I believe so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling Polymer paper-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650000/styling-polymer-paper-slider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox of the `<paper-checkbox>` has an ID of `"checkbox"`, so you could imperatively get a reference to it with [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) syntax (`this.$.myPaperCheckbox.$.checkbox`) to style the inner checkbox's border radius (`checkbox.style.borderRadius`):

```
attached: function() {
  // <paper-checkbox id="myPaperCheckbox">
  this.$.myPaperCheckbox.$.checkbox.style.borderRadius = '50%';
}
```

*Result:*
[image: unchecked circular checkbox]
[image: checked circular checkbox]

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wrqqXy?editors=1010)

You might also consider switching to [`<paper-radio-button>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-button/elements/paper-radio-button), which already uses a circular checkbox (but with a different/circular checkmark).